# How i convert Raw seed to Private Key in Substrate

Tags: polkadot-js, keyring

I have a toy example : My keypair is `ed25519`

```
const seed = [
   40, 246, 184,  64,  69, 145, 132, 131,
  231,  66, 112, 159, 162,  36,  79, 197,
   62,  54, 222, 103, 122, 190,   7, 143,
   94, 190, 180,  76,  87, 182, 115, 236
]
```

`seed` is `Uint8Array(32)` type

How I convert `seed` into `private key` in `Substrate` with `polkadotjs` api

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Keypair and with it you can obtain the Public Key, the Address and sign transactions.

But the keyring does not expose the private key. It manages all signing operations on your behalf.

A code example to do that from your seed:

```
const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'ed25519' })
const seed = [
    40, 246, 184,  64,  69, 145, 132, 131,
   231,  66, 112, 159, 162,  36,  79, 197,
    62,  54, 222, 103, 122, 190,   7, 143,
    94, 190, 180,  76,  87, 182, 115, 236
 ]
// add the account, encrypting it, override to ed25519
const keys = keyring.addFromSeed(Uint8Array.from(seed), { name: 'hex seed acc' },'ed25519');
console.log(keys.publicKey);
console.log(keys.address);
const signature = keys.sign("message");
console.log(signature);
```

Comment: Dont we have another way to expose our private key from raw seed/mnemonic phrase?